# About Virtual Box Networking

Tags: networking, virtualbox

I've been reading online about networking with virtual box 4. I would like some advice.

I have a guest Ubuntu with apache and a Windows 7 machine with IIS. I want to make the host and guest comunicate with each other for testing and "educational" purpouses. So far i used the bridget mode and it worked fine but my machine was part of my company Network.

I would like a way to make some private network with the host and the guest but also have internet connection on both using the host's internet connection.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 1):

You can do this through NAT instead of Bridge mode, but you will need to adjust config files to allow ports per VM, last time I checked NAT controls don't existing in the GUI, but I could be wrong.

If bridge is acceptable though it will be your simplest way.